# Allocating memory for an array of struct i get an error

Tags: c, data-structures, allocation

the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 20

typedef struct word{

    char word[20];
    int occurrance;
} word;

int array_word_creator(word *array, FILE *fp);
void initialize(word array[], int max);
void comparator(word array[], int max, FILE *fp);
void printer(word array[], int max);





int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f_sent, *f_words;
    word *array;
    int arr_lenght=0;
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("Wrong argument number, please use NAME FILE1 FILE2;\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((f_sent=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL||(f_words=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't find or open the files, please check if the name is correct\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    arr_lenght=array_word_creator(array, f_words);
    comparator(array, arr_lenght ,f_sent);
    printer(array, arr_lenght);

    return 0;
}

int array_word_creator(word *array, FILE *fp)
{
    int n,i=0;
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);
    *array= malloc(n*sizeof(word));
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s", array[i].word)!=EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }
    initialize(array,n);

    return n;
}

void initialize(word array[], int max)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        array[i].occurrance=0;
    }
}

void comparator(word array[], int max, FILE *fp)
{
    char word[MAX];
    int i;
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s", word)!=EOF)
    {
        for(i=0;i<max;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(word, array[i].word)==0)
            {
                array[i].occurrance++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printer(word array[], int max)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        if(array[i].occurrance>0)
        {
            printf("The word '%s' occurs %d times\n", array[i].word, array[i].occurrance);
        }
    }
}
```

And the compiler says me:

```
C:\Users\Matteo\Google Drive\Programming\C\lab3\es1\main.c|47|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'word' from type 'void *'|
```

I just studied memory allocation so i'm having some trouble with it, especially with structures. If possible, plase link me also some good docs about this subject.

thank you!

Comment: Type of `*array` is a `word`. You can not assign pointer to it. If you want to return allocated pointer from your function, its prototype should be `int array_word_creator(word **array, FILE *fp)`

Comment: Which line is 47?

Comment: It is a struct defined near the top

Comment: @Matagyah first analysis of your source shows that you are using the same name 'word' for both a struct name, a type name and a variable name in the struct name. How you could obtain an error or warning when compiling this part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main` word *array is a pointer to a structure of type word.

You then pass array, which does not point to anything, to the function array_word_creator.

You then try to assign the pointer returned by malloc to where array is pointing, but it doesn't point anywhere yet, and even if it did, it would be pointing to a word (since it is a word *), so it can't store a pointer, hence the compiler error.

If you want to set the array pointer in main to the result of malloc, you have to pass a pointer to the pointer. `int array_word_creator(word **array, FILE *fp)`, then you would call it by doing `array_word_creator(&array, .... )`, the your *array = malloc will work.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
...
arr_lenght = array_word_creator(&array, f_words);
...


int array_word_creator(word **array, FILE *fp)
{
  int n, i = 0;
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
  *array = malloc(n * sizeof(word));
  while (fscanf(fp, "%19s", (*array)[i].word) != EOF)
  {
    i++;
  }
  initialize(*array, n);

  return n;
}
```

Comment: I would change `while (fscanf(fp, "%s", (*array)[i].word) != EOF)` to `while (i < n && fscanf(fp, "%19s", (*array)[i].word) != EOF)`. Also you forgot the `*` in `initialize(*array, n);`.